# Sorting boost results in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have been searching for a similar question, but nothing seems to help me.

I want to sort my query results, but keeping the boost order.

For example I make an `orQuery`, with 3 queries inside with `Occur.SHOULD`, and boost 2.0, 1.0, and 0.2. Then, when I make the sort, I want that the results for boost 2.0 are kept in the top but sorted, then the results for boost 1.0 also sorted and finally the results for the last query (0.2) also sorted.

You can imagine the results as three groups of sorted results.

Is there something that I can use???

Comment: look at this docmentation https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [don't think you can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899258/solr-date-boost-and-sort-by-relevant-results-not-working-properly) out of the box. You can implement your own `Collector` but it would be much easier to simply run three searches separately and merge the results afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of ways to go about this:

**1** - Make the differences in boosts huge.

If the boost factors you apply in the query are large enough, they should override every other score-impacting factor.  So, rather than 0.2, 1.0 and 2.0, you could try .000001, 1.0 and 1000000, for something to try.  Experiment a bit, until you get something usable.  Then, sort by relevance(`Sort.RELEVANCE`), as is the default, and then you not only get the sort you want, but also maintain all the other useful aspects of scoring within those subgroups.

**2** - Actually apply sorting by query boost

This is the option you'll need to take to sort strictly by boost factor, and secondarily, some other sort parameter in a single query.

Lucene's [Sort](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) doesn't give you direct visibility of the boost factor applied to a term (for good reason, it's a bit of a strange thing to want to do.  Boosts are meant to impact the score, not BE the score).  The closest it gives you is sorting by Relevance, which of course, factors in a lot of other things.

If you need to get a raw boost factor, you will need to override the [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html).

There are three boosts to consider:

- Query boost:  Applied as part of the query, this will is passed into `Similarity.computeWeight`
- Field and Document boosts:  Applied at index-time, combined, and stored in the index, combined with a "length norm" factor, as well.

The only boost you seem to be interested in getting is the Query level boost, which should be the easiest to deal with.  You can either modify [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), or just start from scratch creating a subclass of [Similarity].  Either way, you want to stub out most of the logic, and just return the query boost.